# Fourier integral and coefficients in given function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I found this problem while studying and I can't find its solution.

> The function is given $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with this formula: $F=\alpha \sin(\beta w)/w$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both from $\mathbb{R}^+$.
>
> 1. determine $\alpha_0$ and $\beta_0$ from given graph
> 2. if function $F$ is the Fourier transform of certain function $f$, find explicit analytic form of function $f$ and draw it.

I don't know if I can use classic ways to find these coefficients like taking $F(0)$ or $F'(0)$ to determine them. Second part is about solving Fourier integral and basic function graphing I think.

[image]

Comment: Well, you can't use $F(0)$ and $F'(0)$ because $F(0)$ is undefined, as shown on the graph...
The left side of your definition of $F$ should be "$F(w) = ...$".
Are you able to compute $\lim_{w \rightarrow 0} F(w)$?

Comment: I solved it finding period of sine function and with limw→0F(w) and I got α=4/π and β=π. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

(1) Usually, $\sin x$ has period $2\pi$. What is the period of $\sin(\beta x)$? Determine the period from the graph and this will tell you $\beta$. Also, what is $\lim_{w \to 0} F(w)$? This should tell you $\alpha$.

(2) You could do it by inverse Fourier transform as you suggest. What do you get when you try it?

Comment: If I take that period of this function equals 2 and period of sin(βx) can be calculated as T=2π/β then I get that β=π and using limw→0F(w) I get that  α=4/π because  limw→0F(w) is 4 from graph. I checked this using WolframAlpha. After doing inverse Fourier transform I get that my f(t)=i/π for t>-π and f(t)=-i/π when t<-π. After checking for Fourier transform I got that my F(iw)=(-2icos(wt))/πw for α=4/π and  β=π. I feel that I'm missing something or that I made some mistake while integrating and calculating but I can't figure out what. Thanks for help!